# How to verify that the SNS message received was indeed from the source it claims to be?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-sns

I have an API gateway which consumes messages from a SNS. I want to restrict access for that gateway to that particular SNS only. The message that the SNS sends looks like this:

```
{
  Type: 'Notification',
  MessageId: 'ede628f8-0030-5474-97fd-719c9e12c8fa',
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:**********:nonProxySns',
  Message: 'Hello there general kenobi',
  Timestamp: '2021-07-11T07:21:06.862Z',
  SignatureVersion: '1',
  Signature: 'naQKEubdiRV7Djn3UT5XMr3+JUgutprutYMixooreb5/56CRfqwbQXUTcbF02Ww2J/SPoc+NZJc5BRSa7hMviO8ega76k4CjEClJzuU1iWmaX1rGjGotrMex7CXQJQC/YQcqF1uk1yPCri3atjuy2Dz3ywZXCxezTq8/Uom/sLVwlADIsYR+6/2kECdUjbV5Elw4r12MMIDJTm+8pGErlFW5TSS/Zg1ir6HidfMVhiWaQ+tv1alytfqbHWjbsQYP8+R1gtONZGN6W7zA7lcQkzE+qaGyj1LFRoqaDrFZXWXVV5XM8wSkHG/fVDd9jYmE3Bn+Z4GD7W2usN09tq2ecg==',
  SigningCertURL: 'https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-num1.pem',
  UnsubscribeURL: 'https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:**********:nonProxySns:0a0015fc-1da4-4d6d-986a-9a33609a4c8e'
}
```

I see the signature and the signing cert url, but I think that is to verify that the message is not modified in transit. How do I verify that the source of this SNS is the trusted SNS, and not some random person, sending me the exact message?

Comment: did you look into restricting access to your API by using IAM conditions? Might be worth looking into condition operators like `ArnEquals` along with the ARN of the topic...

Comment: @Korgen Will look into it